# Getting cell data into variables in ADF

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf

I have a row iterator that goes through excel sheet and gets every cell value in that row. I have successfully printed the values out, row by row, but I'd now like to store each cell in a row in separate variables so that I can pass them to Application Module where they will be used as parameters in an insert function. How to store cell value in variables ? Thanks. Here is the code:

```
            try {

            InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            System.out.print("File is up and the size is " + file.getLength() + " bytes\n");


            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            if (rowIterator.hasNext())
                rowIterator.next();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");

                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");

                       // System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+ "\t");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");

            }
            // workbook.close();
            // file.close();

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.print("greška");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to do this. Iterate through every row and store it in an arrayList, and then store every ArrayList into another ArrayList. It should look like this ArrayList>. After you get that object send it to your Application module where you "unpack" your ArrayList with an enhanced for loop. After that extract elements from the array into variables and insert them in your view object.